# Actualizar un UPDATE en una página PHP sin volver a cargar la página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy creando una tienda online, y en la parte del backend tengo una pestaña llamada PEDIDOS. Dentro de esa pestaña tengo todos los pedidos y uno de los campos es editable (mediante un desplegable en una ventana modal)
[image: Este es el backend de pedidos]
Cuando hago un cambio en el ESTADO DEL PEDIDO y guardo cambios, se actualiza en la base de datos, pero no se ve automáticamente en la página, a no ser que vuelvas a refrescarla. Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de poder ver los cambios en el momento en la página de PEDIDOS al cerrar la ventana modal.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Kora, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Depues has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Asi como está , la pregunta es muy amplia y es motivo de cierre. Un saludo.

Comment: Para eso tienes que implementar un sistema asíncrono y en "tiempo real", mediante websockets y eventos o similar. Echale un vistazo a https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io o https://github.com/walkor/Workerman por ejemplo.

Comment: Usa Ajax, es lo que yo hago.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Buscaré algo en Ajax, parecido a lo que necesito. Estoy empezando con Javascript así que no tengo mucha idea. Pero sabiendo que se hace con ese lenguaje, lo intentaré y os comento la solución

Comment: En realidad ajax no es un lenguaje es una tecnología de javascript que permite enviar datos a tu servidor y reciviendo una respuesta del mismo. Puedes usar axios o jquery, si no quieres enredarte con los métodos nativos de javascript para esos fines. Suerte

Comment: Ajax será tu mejor aliado para eso. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo que hace algo similar](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/6fju-td04) (pulsa `Run - F9` para probarlo). En este caso el código busca según un `id` en la base de datos y te actualiza el formulario con los datos traídos desde el servidor sin necesidad de refrescar la página. El concepto es el mismo, sólo que en vez de un `SELECT` harías un `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te lo mencionaron en los comentarios la solución es usar [Websockets](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) o [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), usar [AJAX con JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) es bastante cómodo, ya tiene métodos para ese fin, por ejemplo para hacer un post

```
$.post("ajax.php", {arg: 1}, function(result){
    $("#container_div").html(result);
});
```

con esto haces un petición al servidor del tipo post y este te responde con un html y esa respuesta la muestra en container_div, espero que te sea de ayuda, te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre [REST](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transferencia_de_Estado_Representacional) te pude dar algunas ideas sobre tu proyecto

Answer (score 1):

Como no muestras código, es un poco difícil adaptarlo, he realizado lo mismo con AJAX, con una función en la que selecciono el id del elemento contenedor a refrescar, en este caso`tabla.ajax.reload();`. te dejo parte del código que utilice. espero te pueda ayudar en algo.

```
function guardaryeditar(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //No se activara la accion predeterminada del evento
    $("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled", true);
    var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "../ajax/articulo.php?op=guardaryeditar",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

       success: function(datos)
       {
            mostrarform(false);
            tabla.ajax.reload();
       }
     });

limpiar();  
}
```